# Type ModalBackdropComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MyModule and AppModule

Tags: arrays, angular, upgrade, ng2-bootstrap

Environment: Angular 2 RC5, [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap).. Upgrading from RC4 to RC5

Error:

```
Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:4200/app/forgot-username/forgot-username.component.html:39:60
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Type ModalBackdropComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: Myodule and AppModule!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: Type ModalBackdropComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MyModule and AppModule!
    at new BaseException (http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:23)
```

Here's MyModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [   DynamicFormModule, routes ],
  declarations: [ MODAL_DIRECTIVES, ForgotUsernameComponent ],
  exports:      [ ],
  providers:    [BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS,  ]
})
```

App Module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        // FormsModule,
        routing,
        HttpModule,
        ForgotUsernameModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        // AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {


}
```

I have not declared any ng2-bootstrap related artifacts ([ModalBackdropComponent](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/2b95c95b375555bbfd64e9b35e28033c0b21146c/components/modal/modal-backdrop.component.ts) or any other) in AppModule as you can see. So I'm trying to figure out why Angular 2 thinks that I have declared them. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `ModalBackdropComponent` to it's own module (or to another module for shared components and directives and import the shared module where you want to use shared components instead of importing the components directly to several modules.

Comment: Opend an issue with that project. Is there any way to solve this by refactoring my code? https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/873

Comment: I don't know this project. Usually the workaround is to not add this component to directives anywhere but only to declarations of one single `NgModule` and then import this `NgModule` to every other `NgModule` where you want to use the `ModalBackdropComponent`.

Comment: Can you please eloborate on what you mean by " but only to declarations of one single NgModule and then import this NgModule to every other NgModule where you want to use the ModalBackdropComponent.."?

Comment: You create a new module for the `ModalBackdropComponent` and add `ModalBackdropComponent` to `declarations: [...]` and to `exports: [...]`. That's it. This way you can make the `ModalBackdropComponent` available to other `NgModule`s by adding the backdrop module to `imports: []` See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: I did everything like @GünterZöchbauer wrote, but getting an error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null` . Did somebody face the  same error?

Comment: @dantey89 perhaps https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10671 contains something useful.